# How to refactor spaghetti code

Tags: java, refactoring

in my application I have one service with about 2000 line which I want to refactor. I create couple of smaller service and divide method with the big one to smaller. So now I have for example `groupService` which just work wich groups, `playerService` which just work with player and so on. Problem is that sometimes service A need service B to do some work.

Example: I have `playOffService` which works with playOff (Creating updating...) and `finalStandingService`. And when updating playOff I also need update finalStanding. How should I solve this problem ? Just add finalStandingService to PlayOffService or is there some better sollution ?

Comment: Read http://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html

Comment: well it's really pretty simple.  Add marinara sauce, and let it sit for about 5-10 mins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about **dependencies**, and this is a frequent problem in Object Oriented software design.  Have a look at the Wikipedia article on [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

I don't necessarily recommend going to the extent of bringing in a new library to accomplish this for you, especially if you are new to this and can't fully evaluate the libraries yourself, but you may find some useful patterns.

And *please please please* write full unit tests of your service before you start refactoring it!  Keep them passing as you refactor small pieces one at a time.  By the time you are done, you will thank yourself!

Comment: sir yes sir tests are my priority too